Computing the spin of the longitudinal and transverse components of a vector field
Considering the generators of the Lie algebra of $SO(3)$:
\begin{eqnarray}
    J_1=\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
  0 & 0 & 0 \\
  0 & 0 & -i \\
  0 & i & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right),\, J_2=\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
  0 & 0 & i \\
  0 & 0 & 0 \\
  -i & 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right),\,J_3=\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
  0 & -i & 0 \\
  i & 0 & 0 \\
  0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right),
\end{eqnarray}
and the Casimir operator:
\begin{eqnarray}
    J^2=J^2_1+J^2_2+J^2_3=2\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
  1 & 0 & 0 \\
  0 & 1 & 0 \\
  0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right),
\end{eqnarray}
which satisfy eigenvalue equations:
\begin{eqnarray}
J^2 e_{jm} \;&=&\;j(j+1) e_{jm}\,,\\
J_3 e_{jm} \;&=&\;m \,e_{jm}\,,
\end{eqnarray}
how to demonstrate explicitly that the longitudinal and transverse parts, $A$ and $B_\mu$, of a massless vector field $V_\mu = \partial_\mu A + B_\mu$, where $\partial_\mu B^\mu=0$, have spin $0$ and $1$?
